# Wordpress Change Active Submenu Color

Tags: css, wordpress

This problem is really consuming too much of my time and I couldn't seem to get the right CSS code for it. So here's my straightforward question:

**How do I change the text color/background of the active submenu? With active, I mean the submenu page is where I am currently in.**

I would like to change it because this is what's happening on my menu rn:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1ncE.png

The blue bg and text color btw is autogenerated as it is my theme's accent color. I am not sure if the CSS I am adding are just being overridden or not. I am not familiar with CSS as well.
I have no problems on the Parent Pages. Just the active submenu ones.

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Comment: The class should be "current_page_item", is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.current_page_item {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

If this works your CSS is just overwritten. You could go with the "!important" but have in mind that this steals a little performance.

Comment: Sorry, I think your answer is the one I am pertaining to but it doesn't change anything for my menu :( Maybe this class is being overwritten. Any idea whereelse I can find it? I have added the code to the style.css and to the theme.css on my theme folder.